# Global Variables in a WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables, wordpress-admin

I am trying to create my first WordPress plugin. Even in trying to create the install function, things are being a pain.

I want to set some `global variables` specific to my plugin rather than putting the literal values throughout the various functions. However, my install function does not pick up these `global variables`.

Here is my code so far:

```
$version = '1.0a';
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'install' );
function install() {
  global $version;
  add_option( 'test_version', $version );
}
```

Obviously this is pretty straight forward on my end. Any ideas what is going wrong here??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out if you want a global variable for your install function, you must declare it to be global.

```
global $version = '1.0a';
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'install' );
function install() {
  global $version;
  add_option( 'test_version', $version );
}
```

More information can be found at the link below under the "A Note on Variable Scoping" section: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

Comment: My PHP doesn't like `global $var = 'value'`. Instead, I have to do `global $var; $var = 'value';`. Not sure how you got it to work like that.